# java - The method replace(char, char) is undefined for the type Scanner

Tags: java, string, replace, letter

This is my code: https://gyazo.com/8bf55245851665b91d482859b6413a75

I want to replace the first letter of the first word with the first letter of the second word but the replace tool won't work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. An image of your code is not helpful. You should include the *relevant code* as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Why do you expect that a `Scanner` object has a `replace` method?  Did you read the Javadoc for `Scanner`?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/5221149)

Answer (score 1):

In your code  there is no
    String sc
That you have used in the line for replacing the character.
Use this line instead;

```
String replace1=fword1.replace(flfw,flsw);
```

I am referring to line  27 of your code.

And you don't require those for loops there.

Thank You.

Comment: Thank you works! But I dont understand why you say that I don't require those loops?

Comment: These loops are totally not required as you have no set of code repeat any number if times. Hope you get it.

Comment: If an answer to any of your question is correct then better mark it as accepted(by clicking on the tick mark beside the answer) so that another user who has the same question can get the right answer from the pool of answers received

Comment: Please note I am not asking you to to do the same with my answer I told this for your information only.Hope you understand.